# Select the closest week-day in a range

Tags: sql, date, join

I have a table "stocks_prices" with entries gvkey, iid, datecol and prccd. It represents the price (prccd) of a stock (represented by its gvkey and iid) on datecol (YYYY-MM-DD). I want to look in all my data and on the same row having the price on the first day of the month and next to it the price on datecol - 35 days (ie what was its price 35 days before), but it needs to be a week-day (no entries on week-ends).

For now I have that :

```
    SELECT b1.gvkey, b1.iid, b1.datecol, b1.prccd, 
        b2.datecol as '35days', (b2.prccd - b1.prccd)/b1.prccd
    FROM stocks_prices b1
        LEFT JOIN stocks_prices b2
            ON b1.datecol = DATE_ADD(b2.datecol, INTERVAL 35 DAY) 
            AND b1.gvkey = b2.gvkey
            AND b1.iid = b2.iid
    WHERE b1.datecol in ('2015-01-02', '2015-02-02', '2015-03-02',  '2015-04-01',  '2015-05-01',  '2015-06-01',  '2015-07-01',  '2015-08-03',  '2015-09-01',
      '2015-10-01',  '2015-11-02',  '2015-12-01')
```

It works, but not exactly the way I want (it looks exactly 35 days back, I'd like it take the closest date available). I hope it is not a trivial question, I'm just getting started with MySQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results are helpful in communicating what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WEEKDAY` function to obtain the closest weekday at the beginning of the month:

- If the first day is a Saturday, then use the next Monday
- If the first day is a Sunday, then use the next Monday
- Else, use itself.

Here's the implementation :

```
SELECT
    CASE WEEKDAY(datecol) 
        WHEN 5 THEN DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL 2 DAY) -- Sat  Mon
        WHEN 6 THEN DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL 1 DAY) -- Sun  Mon
        ELSE datecol
    END AS first_weekday
FROM stocks_prices
```

Since -35 days is exactly 5 weeks ago. So the weekday of the current `datecol` is the same as 5 weeks ago. And here's the result :

```
SELECT
    b1.gvkey,
    b1.iid,
    b1.datecol,
    b1.prccd, 
    b2.datecol as '35days',
    (b2.prccd - b1.prccd)/b1.prccd
FROM stocks_prices b1
    LEFT JOIN stocks_prices b2
        ON b1.datecol = DATE_ADD(b2.datecol, INTERVAL 35 DAY) 
        AND b1.gvkey = b2.gvkey
        AND b1.iid = b2.iid
WHERE b1.datecol IN
(
    SELECT
        CASE(WEEKDAY(datecol))
            WHEN 5 THEN DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL 2 DAY) -- Sat -> Mon
            WHEN 6 THEN DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL 1 DAY) -- Sun -> Mon
            ELSE datecol
        END
    FROM stocks_prices
    WHERE DAY(datecol) = 1
)
```